# Use a key which is the value of a constant in a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

Please check the code below:

```
my %hash = (
123 => "a",
456 => "b",
); 
use constant x_1 => 123;
use constant x_2 => 456;
```

I want to use something like $hash{x_1}
to get "a". I tried to store x_1 into a variable and then use it as the key, it worked.
Like

```
my $var = "x_1"; # or my $var = x_1
```

But when I get the variable x_1 from an array which I store into a variable, and then try to access the hash from this variable, it shows an error.
Like

```
my @arr;
$arr[0]{"y_1"} = "x_1";
$arr[0]{"z_1"} = "x_2";
my $newVar = $arr[0]{"y_1"};#$newVar = x_1
print $hash{$newVar}; #this shows error.
```

How could I use the variable not as a string but as a constant here?

Comment: Syntax error: `$arr{"y_1"} = "x_1";`. Arrays use `[]`. Hashes use `{}`

Comment: The code doesn't even compile, so I'm perplexed at that. Of course, declaring `@arr` and then using `%arr` implies a fundamental misunderstanding, which I think means mucking around with constants is a road to error anyway.

Comment: Also, constants don't interpolate in strings. See [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html)

Comment: Edited again to use array properly

Comment: In the marked duplicate answer, they have used a constant as a hash key, which is fine. I had a different question, when that constant's value is used as a key itself. Is that not different from the marked duplicate question?

Comment: So it is not possible to use a constant's value as a key for a hash. Is this the answer to the question?

Comment: Re "*So it is not possible to use a constant's value as a key for a hash*", It is possible, as shown in the Answer I already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to use something like $hash{x_1} to get "a"*

By using anything but just an identifier, the expression won't be autoquoted. For example, you could use any of the following:

- `$hash{+CONSTANT}`
- `$hash{(CONSTANT)}`

So you could use `$hash{+x_1}` instead of `$hash{x_1}`.

---

> *How could I use the variable not as a string but as a constant here?*

You rightfully ask to be prevented from doing this by adding `use strict;` because it's [dangerous](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) (meaning hard to read, hard to debug, hard to maintain, etc, etc, etc).

Solution 1: Use a lookup table.

```
my %lookup = (
   x_1 => x_1,
   x_2 => x_2,
);

my @arr;
$arr[0]{"y_1"} = "x_1";
$arr[0]{"z_1"} = "x_2";

my $newVar = $arr[0]{"y_1"};
defined( my $key = $lookup{$newVar} )
   or die("Invalid key");

print $hash{$key};
```

Solution 2: Use the constant's value instead of its name.

```
my @arr;
$arr[0]{"y_1"} = x_1;
$arr[0]{"z_1"} = x_2;

my $newVar = $arr[0]{"y_1"};
print $hash{$newVar};
```

Comment: Added answer to second question in Question.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Solution1 and it worked. If I do require the key to be a hexadecimal value, like oct("0x0"), oct("0xff"), then this solution is not working as perl changes the key to decimal values and then it doesn't match the key in hash.And the constant also points to a hex value. Is there is workaround for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a number to hex? `sprintf "%X"`

Comment: Nope. I want it like:: use constant x_1 => oct("0x11");use constant x_2 => oct("0x22"); and then the hash as :: my %hash = (oct("0x11") => "a", oct("0x22") => "b", );. This is not working with solution 1.

Comment: Sure it works. There's no difference between `oct("0x11")`, `0x11` and `17`, and you already said it works for `17`.

Answer (score 0):

A constant is just a Perl subroutine, and a variable that holds the name of a subroutine or a reference to a subroutine can be dereferenced to invoke the subroutine.

```
use constant x_1 => 123;
my %hash = (123 => 'a', 456 => 'b');
my @arr = ( { y_1 => 'x_1', z_1 => 'x_2' } );

#   $arr[0]{y_1}  holds 'x_1'
#   $arr[0]{y_1}->()   calls  'x_1'->(),  or  &x_1()
#   can also say  &{$arr[0]{y_1}}
my $key = $arr[0]{y_1}->();
print $hash{$key};            # 'a'
```

These constructions are frowned upon under `use strict` (you do `use strict`, don't you?), which means you may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: Re "*These constructions are frowned upon under `use strict`*",  Suggested rephrasing: *You rightfully ask to be prevented from doing this by adding `use strict;` because it is [dangerous](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).*